# recursively copy all files from one directory to another with exceptions

Tags: linux

How do i need copy all files except a couple of directories from one directory to another.
for eg:

```
cp -R test /www/test2 would copy all
```

But i want to exclude 2 folders called log and logs.

I tried something like:

```
find ~test -not -name logs,log |  cp -R test /www/test2
```

But can you help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use rsync:

```
rsync -a --exclude=logs --exclude=log from/ to/
```

Comment: the rynsc kinda worked cool for me!

Comment: rsync is now my new friend :) Thanks, the explanation is neat

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
find dir -type d ! \( -name 'log' -o -name 'logs' \) | xargs -I{} cp -R {} /www/test2/{}
```

Comment: @sputnick see my changes.  Feel free to offer up the emacs regex for this if you happen to know it.

Answer (score 0):

If using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -R test/!(log|logs) /www/test2
```

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

Comment: What happens when the structure is like so: `test/someotherdir/logs`?  OP never said `log` and `logs` was the second-highest directory.

Comment: If you re-read OP command `find ~test -not -name logs,log` log & logs should be a sub-dir.

Comment: `find` looks recursively through *all* sub-directories.  File globbing doesn't.  For your answer to work, `log` and `logs` would have to be *immediate* sub-directories of `test`.